# the convergence of the infinite product of matrices composed by matrces with the spectral radius less than 1

Tags: matrices, convergence-divergence, infinite-product, spectral-radius

Suppose the two matrices $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ have the spectral radius less than $1$.
Do the infinite product $\mathbf{C}\left( 1 \right)\mathbf{C}\left( 2 \right)\cdots $ , where  each $\mathbf{C}\left( t \right),\ t=1,2,\cdots $ is  $\mathbf{A}$ or $\mathbf{B}$, converge to $\mathbf{o}$ ?
 I tried to prove it using Jordan canonical forms or matrix norms, but I couldn't. Please tell me how to prove this claim or show the counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

For a counterexample, let $A,B$ be given by
\begin{align*}
A&=
\pmatrix{
0&\frac{1}{4}\\
-1&1\\
}
\\[4pt]
B&=
\pmatrix{
0&-\frac{1}{4}\\
1&1
}
\end{align*}
Then the eigenvalues of $A$ are ${\large{\frac{1}{2}}},{\large{\frac{1}{2}}}$, and the eigenvalues of $B$ are also ${\large{\frac{1}{2}}},{\large{\frac{1}{2}}}$, so each of $A,B$ has spectral radius less than $1$.

Computing $AB$, we get
$$
AB
=
\pmatrix{
\frac{1}{4}&\frac{1}{4}\\
1&\frac{5}{4}\\
}
$$
which has eigenvalues
$$
\frac{3}{4}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\;\frac{3}{4}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
$$
so $AB$ has spectral radius greater than $1$.

It follows that $(AB)^n$ doesn't approach $0$ as $n$ approaches infinity.

Comment: Dear quasi
Thank you for your answer.
Are there any sufficient conditions except that A commutes with B?
In my actual problem, B=A+some additional factor in a few entries.
In that case, are there any sufficient condition for the relation between A and additional factors?

Comment: @Masahiro Fujimoto: Given that you asked for a proof or counterexample, that's all I aimed for. If you have further conditions on $A,B$, perhaps ask a new question as a followup to this one (with a link back to this one).